# Filtering Firebase notifications before they are displayed by the client (either Android or iOS)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

It is my understanding that whenever Firebase notifications are sent to client devices, one of these 3 situations takes place:

- the application is in the `foreground`. Dedicated handlers are called to process incoming messages (including notifications). The application processes the messages and decides or not to create a notification.
- the application is in the `background`. Alternate handlers are called to process incoming messages. For example, for Flutter applications, a message handler is run in a separate isolate. From there, there again, it is possible to either display a notification or to do nothing, based on the payload. Similar alternative handlers are offered eg. in the Android and iOS native client frameworks.
- the application is `not running` (aka `terminated`). In this case, it is my understanding that the operating system itself receives the message and creates a notification.

In the first two scenarios aboves, I can easily filter out specific payloads and choose not to display a notification if the Firebase message has a `notification` field in the payload.

However, in the last scenario, what can I do? Is there some code that is invoked somewhere to allow me to do last-minute filtering, before a notification is generated by the OS?

I know I could do the following: not send the Firebase notification to the client in the first place. However I have a scenario where I need client-side last-resort filtering: I would like to never get notifications originating from a production server when the debug build of my application is running on the device. The debug build uses another server, but unfortunately shares the same FCM tokens.